# unexpected behaviour of assign a value to a field of a struct of union

Tags: c

```
typedef union { unsigned x; } T;

T a;
a.x = 3;

int main() { return 0; }
```

Trying to compile this code, with `gcc t.c`, I get

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

using

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

When I move `a.x = 3;` inside `main`, it behaves as expected.

I wish to find the passage from

```
ISO/IEC 9899:TC3
```

where it is explained that it is forbidden to assign values to a union in global namespace.

---

EDIT: with structures it happens the same.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that this is a union. Assignments are statements, and statements are not allowed outside a function. You are perhaps looking for initialization. That would be allowed.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your question.  It seems like the entire part about unions is completely irrelevant, and all that you're after is what part of the spec says that statements have to be inside functions.  Is that correct?  If so, you should rewrite the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Declarations are statements as well...

Comment: Yes, with structures it happens the same. I need to find in the definition of the C language where it is stated this. I asked for unions, for you to be able to test the code.

Comment: @alinsoar- Out of curiosity, why do you need to know the exact part of the C spec that disallows this?

Comment: Because it is my reference book for C, where I am looking there for answers.

Comment: @K-ballo in C++ a declaration is a statement, but in C a declaration is not a statement.

Comment: @K-ballo C99's 6.8.2:1 says that declarations are not statements.

Comment: In C99 and C11, you can initialize any member of a union (even outside a function) with: `T a = { .x = 3 };`.  In C89, you could not use the designated initializer and could only initialize the first member of the union.  You can't write assignments (as distinct from initializers) outside a function in any version of standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to find the passage from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 where it is explained that it is forbidden to assign values to a union in global namespace.

It is described in the 6.9p1 of C99 (syntax of a translation-unit). You cannot have a statement outside of a function.

Comment: That part of the C spec says that you *must* have a compound statement  as part of a function, not that you *can't* have a statement outside of a function.

Comment: 6.9.1p1 provides the Backus Naur form for `function-definition`

Answer (score 0):

What you *cannot* do is usually implicit rather than explicit in a language spec, since there are an infinite number of things you can't do. And, in fact, you *can* assign values to a union in a global namespace unless you want to insist that "assign" cannot refer to initialization. The C99 syntax for initializing a member of a global union goes like this:

```
typedef union { unsigned x; } T;

T a = {.x = 3};
```

Same answer for structures, of course.

Comment: You will find the definition of an *assignment expression* in the C99 standard at 6.5.16. It is definitely and explicitly disjoint from what a declaration with initializer is in 6.7:1. There is no need to “insist” that they are different, they lie in completely different parts of the grammar.