# Struct assignment globally gives name type error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have a struct like this in "parser.h"

```
struct obj{
        char *filename;
        unsigned long nverts;
        unsigned long curvert;
        double (*verts)[3]; 
        unsigned int *faces[3]; 
};

typedef obj obj;
```

and in parser.cpp

I am declaring

```
  obj objmesh;

    objmesh.filename="c://temp//wings.obj";
    objmesh.nverts = 20;
    objmesh.verts = (double (*)[3]) malloc( objmesh.nverts *  sizeof(double[3]) );
    objmesh.curvert = 0;
```

When I do these assigments at the top of the parser.cpp I get "'objmesh' does not name a type" error.

But when I put all these assignments in a function in parser.cpp (while obj objmesh; has global scope) , I get no error and compiles fine.

Can anyone think of a reason why that is the case? I am using Mingw Gnu 4.6 C++ compiler

Comment: Are you saying that assignment is not in a function?

Comment: Mats, when the assignments are global I get an error. When the assignments are in a function but the declaration still global , I get no error.

Comment: Are you writing C or C++? Because the C++ answer (use a constructor) wont work in C

Comment: possible duplicate of [unexpected behaviour of assign a value to a field of a struct of union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760531/unexpected-behaviour-of-assign-a-value-to-a-field-of-a-struct-of-union)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your assignments inside a function, e.g:

```
obj objmesh;

... 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
... possibly other stuff here... 
    objmesh.filename="c://temp//wings.obj";
    objmesh.nverts = 20;
    objmesh.verts = (double (*)[3]) malloc( objmesh.nverts *  sizeof(double[3]) );
    objmesh.curvert = 0;
... More code here ... 
}
```

By the way:
`double (*)[3])` begs for a typedef...

Comment: Hmm I see. I do not have main function. These will be part of function files. Btw that was the only way I was able to compile and make the memory allocation for the struct member. Is there any better way if you will?

Comment: Well, you need to put it inside SOME function. I choose main because it's the first thing that gets executed first. 

How about `typedef double vect3[3]; `
then uses `vect3* verts;` and `verts = (vect3*) mallloc(...)`

Comment: +1 Assigning a string-literal to that `char *` isn't exactly giving me warm-fuzzies either. Ugh.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Because when you do the assignments individually you're essentially executing  instructions for each assignment, which in C must be in a function.

You can however do static initialization (as long as the values are fixed). Static initialization is fulfilled by the compiler at compile time, so no instructions are executed to set the values of the struct.

```
double verts[20][3];

obj objmesh = {
    "c://temp//wings.obj",
    20,
    verts, /* declared above, not dynamically allocated */
    0
    };
```

If you must dynamically allocate 'verts', then this won't work for you.

Comment: PQuinn thank you for offering a second solution. So lets me choose only one solution, so i had to go with the first solution. Thanks again